# Vim "set noundofile" doesn't work, Vim still creates undo files

Tags: vim

Even though I I added "set noundofile" in the "_vimrc" file in the installation directory of Vim it still creates undo files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You have no business editing anything in Vim's installation directory. Whatever you do to configure Vim *must* happen in *your* own runtime directory, located in *your* own "home directory", and nowhere else:

   ```
   %USERPROFILE%\vimfiles
   ```

   If it doesn't already exist, create it yourself.
2. Disabling undo files is indeed done with `set noundofile`, that you are supposed to put in *your* own `vimrc`, under the directory mentioned above:

   ```
   %USERPROFILE%\vimfiles\vimrc
   ```

   That file is sourced *after* any system-level `vimrc` so whatever you put in that file will take precedence. It is *your* `vimrc`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it worked. What I did worked as well but it's not really an elegant thing to do, I must agree now that I see the alternative.